# Time format in automated email is "general" rather than hh:nn AM/PM

Tags: excel, vba, time, outlook, format

I have an Excel spreadsheet that lists dates in one column and times in another.

My Outlook VBA code pulls the dates/times and puts them in an email.

In the spreadsheet, they are formatted as "1:30 PM" (for example), using the "Format Cells" feature in Excel.

If I just pull the values from the spreadsheet using, for example,

```
.Body = xlSht.Range("A2")
```

It shows up as 0.375, or another number in "general" form.

If I first format the time using this code,

```
Dim Time1 As Object
Set Time1 = xlSht.Range("B2")
Time1 = Format(Time1, "hh:nn AM/PM")
'[...]
.Body = Time1
```

It still shows up in the email as 0.375.

Is there a different way I should be approaching this?

Comment: Why ***nn*** rather than ***mm*** ??

Answer (score 1):

Use `Format$` to apply your format:

```
.Body =  Format$(xlSht.Range("B2").Value, "hh:mm AM/PM")
```

Datetimes are just numbers in Excel; applying formatting in Excel doesn't change the underlying value, hence the need for `Format$` if you're reading the value from a cell.

Answer (score 1):

*Note, this answer is (additionally to BigBen's answer) meant as an explanation why your code did not work as expected:*

So what actually happens with the following code

```
Dim Time1 As Object
Set Time1 = xlSht.Range("B2")
Time1 = Format(Time1, "hh:nn AM/PM")
.Body = Time1
```

is that it is more precisely written exactly the same as …

```
Dim Time1 As Object
Set Time1 = xlSht.Range("B2")   'now Time1 is a Range object
Time1.Value = Format(Time1, "hh:nn AM/PM")
.Body = Time1.Value
```

If you declare `Dim Time1 As Object` and then `Set Time1 = xlSht.Range("B2")` the `Time1` variable is a **reference** to the cell B2. That means from now on writing `Time1` is actually *exactly* the same as writing `xlSht.Range("B2")` just shorter!

That means if you now convert the value of that cell `0.375` into a string `Format(Time1, "hh:nn AM/PM")` which is `09:00 AM` then `Time1 = Format(Time1, "hh:nn AM/PM")` writes this string back into the cell B2 (represented by `Time1`).
It is actually the same as writing:

```
xlSht.Range("B2") = Format(Time1, "hh:nn AM/PM")
```

**And now happens what happens when Excel starts thinking and guessing:**
Excel sees you writing that string `09:00 AM` and *thinks*: *"Ah, the user want's to write a time/date, so let's be smart and convert that string into a date value (so we can calculate with it)."* So it converts it into a number which is actually `0.375` and whoops you are back where you started!

Now there are 2 ways to get around that issue:

1. Don't declare `Time1 As Object` but as String.

   ```
   Dim Time1 As String
   Time1 = xlSht.Range("B2").Value 'no Set!
   ```

   So the line `Time1 = Format(Time1, "hh:nn AM/PM")` does not write it back into the cell but only into the variable `Time1`.
2. Or alternatively make sure that when writing it back into the cell, that Excel will understand it as `Text` and does not try to convert it into a time/date again by adding a `'` as first character (this will not show up in the cell):

   ```
   Dim Time1 As Range 'spcifying it as range instead of object is more precise (a range is an object)
   Set Time1 = xlSht.Range("B2")
   Time1 = "'" & Format(Time1, "hh:nn AM/PM")  'this will write the date as text into the cell
   ```

   Note that is highly not recommended to write a date/time as text into a cell. You cannot calculate with it anymore. So I recommend to the first option.

Comment: I understood the question to be about pulling the time from Excel into an email...

Comment: @BigBen yes, you are probably right, I think the same and your answer works perfectly (got my vote). I just thought it might be worthy to explain why this happened and why the OP's code did not work as expected. So this is more thought to be an explanation than a solution.

Comment: ^^^^ Ah gotcha. Though I inwardly cringe when I see `Dim Time1 as String`!

Comment: @BigBen yep, that was just to show the difference between an object reference and a normal variable (that contains a value) is. I generally would do it exactly as in your answer.

Comment: I guess my point was, if you do `Dim Time1 As String`, then `Time1 = "0.375"`, right? Unless you meant `Time1 = xlSht.Range("B2").Text` and not `.Value`?

Comment: @BigBen yes, I know it is an unnecessary type conversion. But I didn't want to make it even more confusing and tried to stick close to the original code. But yes, you are right. Better would have been: `Dim Time1 As String: Time1 = Format(xlSht.Range("B2").Value, "hh:nn AM/PM") `

Comment: Got it - that makes more sense (you have my upvote :-))